# /usr/bin/ld: cannot found -lvtkRenderingOpenGL

Tags: opencv, c++11, cmake, realsense

when a run `make` in ubuntu16.04,the error occurs:

```
Scanning dependencies of target realsense_readPic
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/realsense_readPic.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable realsense_readPic
/usr/bin/ld: canot found -lvtkRenderingOpenGL
/usr/bin/ld: canot found -lvtkImagingHybrid
/usr/bin/ld: canot found -lvtkIOImage
/usr/bin/ld: canot found -lvtkCommonDataModel
.......//There's an omission here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/realsense_readPic.dir/build.make:139: recipe for target 'realsense_readPic' failed
make[2]: *** [realsense_readPic] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/realsense_readPic.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/
```

realsense_readPic.dir/all] Error 2
    Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
    make: *** [all] Error 2

I ran a very simple program, the following is the source code, I do not know what went wrong, I have tried a lot of online methods, but no effect.

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
#include<librealsense2/rs.hpp>

int main() try
{
...
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(realsense_readPic)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")

aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
add_executable(realsense_readPic ${SRC_LIST})

find_package( OpenCV 3.2.0 REQUIRED )
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(realsense_readPic ${OpenCV_LIBS})

set(DEPENDENCIES realsense2 )
target_link_libraries(realsense_readPic ${DEPENDENCIES})
```

and when I run `locate libvtkRenderingOpenGL.so`,there is nothing.
the error has disturbed me several days.I am looking forward to your reply.

Comment: this error also occurs in some other programs .

Comment: Have you tried installing vtk? It might not be included with OpenCV.

Comment: I succeed by install `opencv` again.